# Spring Output ANSI enabled doesn't work on Windows terminal

Tags: spring-boot, terminal, ansi-escape

I have enabled ANSI for Spring output using below property in `application.properties`

> spring.output.ansi.enabled=always

When I run the application deom my IntelliJ IDE it displays colors in output. But when I run the same using my windows terminal using the jar, it doesn't show colors, instead it shows some characters.

> ?[2m2021-06-07 12:49:56.382?[0;39m ?[32m INFO?[0;39m ?[35m11312?[0;39m ?[2m---?[0;39m ?[2m[           main]

Output looks like below when I run from IntelliJ IDE.

[image]

Please assist me. What am I missing when I execute through jar file using windows terminal to show colors ?

Comment: I don't think ANSI works in a regular windows shell, but shold work in a PowerShell or Unix based shell.